# How can i assign nested data to a new variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to create a new variable `line` and make it contain nested data.

What I am expecting as result:

```
{
    description: "descriptionString",
    vatInfo    : {
        vatAccount: {
            vatCode   : "vatCode"
        }
    }
}
```

How I am doing it:

```
export function changeProductOnLine(originalLine, product, customer, invoice) {
  let line = { ...originalLine, product }

  if (product) {
    const vatCode = getProductVatCode(line, invoice)
    line.description = buildLineDescription(product.name, product.description)
    line.vatInfo.vatAccount.vatCode = "v10"
    return line
  }
```

Is it correct what I am doing ? Can it work ?

Comment: *"Is it correct what I am doing ? Can it work ?"* We are happy to help with problems in your code, but these are questions you can answer yourself by simply running your code. If you don't get the result you expect you can ask for help and explain the issue.

Comment: As @FelixKling suggested, run your code to find out. If you don't have a place locally to test it, try http://repl.it and select 'JavaScript' as your language and away you go. Also I tried to answer your question anyways...

Comment: Are you sure that `vatAcoount` is the expected output? Or is that actually your input? Maybe the typo occurs in both (which would explain the error)

Comment: @eric redoing a rolled back edit without a consent is not really in the sense of this community.

Comment: @JonasWilms You rolled back an edit that cleared up confusion... That's not helping the OP. We're here to help the OP, not effect change based on feeling. Later on he uses `vatAccount` spelled properly. So it's a known, not an unknown.

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing is close, but you need to keep in mind that when you use a spreader like that, what you'll end up with is this:

```
{
  description: "descriptionString",
  vatInfo    : {
    vatAccount: {
      vatCode   : "vatCode"
    }
  },
  product: {
    description: "descriptionString",
    vatInfo    : {
      vatAccount: {
          vatCode   : "vatCode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I think you want is for `product` to overwrite the values, but not end up with a 'product' property in your object, based on what you explained you wanted. Try this:

```
export function changeProductOnLine(originalLine, product, customer, invoice) {
  if (product) {
    return {
       ...originalLine,
       // since these are the last thing in the new obj it will overwrite anything in the obj
       description: buildLineDescription(product.name, product.description),
       vatInfo: {
         vatAccount : {
           vatCode: getProductVatCode(line, invoice)
         }
       }
    }
  } else {
    return line
  }
}
```

This way, you also don't end up creating a new variable in memory just to modify it slightly then return it. It all happens at once, and ONLY if you have a arg 'product' value other than `undefined` or `null`